# javafx how to achieve density independent design

Tags: java, css, javafx, density-independent-pixel

Hello all,

We are trying to achieve **Density Independent Design** in javaFX.(say if window width of 200px assume it takes 20cm in 88dpi. and if same 200px window size application run in different PPI it should occupy only 20cm). but according to javaFX there is only px unit specify for scene width. so javaFX automatically manage px in different PPI for different screen resolution?

we check this by creating simple hello word application and give stage size to 300x275 and run it into different resolution( *changing resolution manually from OS settings* ) analyze scene size is display differently. so how to achieve Density Independent Design.
             **like dp unit available in Android**.

We try to apply px to dp formula in javaFX. but it is very difficult to find PPI in javaFX means in ubuntu getDpi() method returns 96 in all resolution.

```
Screen.getPrimary().getDpi()/96*px;
```

here we are attaching screen shot for different screen resolution.

[image: 800x600 resolution]

[image: 1024x768 resolution]

[image: 1366x768 resolution]

Comment: Do you mean `Screen#getDPI` returns 96 on various different screens?  If so it may be a bug. See [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095013) related bug report - it describes a way to get the DPI from AWT, which may circumvent this problem.

Comment: Not checked in various screens with different resolution.but checked in one pc and changed resolution from Ubuntu display settings and still return same dpi. Works great in windows pc . Using jdk 6u90

Comment: @mcd Do you really mean jdk6u90?

Comment: @mipa oh sorry it's jdk8 not 6

Comment: One more note: One should also keep in mind that Screen#getDPI does not return the physical DPIs. On my retina mac this function geturns 110 although the physical DPI of its screen is 220. This corresponds to the scale factor 2 which is applied by default to all pixel settings.